# testCafe: Using Role in testscript

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, user-roles

** First problem/question:**

I defined 2 roles in a separate file (/Support/utilities) :

```
import channelsPage from '..'
import config from '../Config/config';
import {Role} from 'testcafe';
import loginPage from '..';

let l1 =  require('../support/global').log[1];
let l0 =  require('../support/global').log[0];

const SuperUser = Role(config.baseUrl, async t => {

  //Log in as superuser
  await loginPage.logIn(l1.username, l1.password)

   //Check if proper site opened

 if (await loginPage.keycloakLoginError.exists) {
        await loginPage.logIn(l1.username, l1.password)
    }
    else {
        await t.expect(channelsPage.lineupsAndPackages.exists).ok();
        await t.expect(channelsPage.createDropUp.exists).ok();

  }
})

const NormalUser = Role(config.baseUrl, async t => {

  //Log in as superuser
  await loginPage.logIn(l0.username, l0.password)

   //Check if proper site opened

 if (await loginPage.keycloakLoginError.exists) {
        await loginPage.logIn(l1.username, l1.password)

    }
    else {
        await t.expect(channelsPage.lineupsAndPackages.exists).ok();
        await t.expect(channelsPage.createDropUp.exists).ok();

  }
})

module.export ={
  SuperUser: SuperUser,
  NormalUser: NormalUser
}
```

and then used one of the defined role:  NormalUser in testscript (another file)

```
import config from './Config/config';
import NormalUser from './Support/utilities';


fixture`SanityTests`
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t.maximizeWindow()
  })
  .page`${config.baseUrl}`;

test('Search', async t => {

  await t.maximizeWindow();

  //Log in
  await t.useRole(NormalUser.NormalUser)
   });
```

The test failed because:
" The "role" argument is expected to be a Role instance, but it was undefined."

When I have these in one file - the test passed, so the problem must be in wrong defined role (how to do it correctly?)

**II Second problem/question**

When I am creating the Role constructor: Role( URL, func( t ) [, options] )
I must point the URL of the login page and then when I create test into fixtures I must configure the fixture - specifying the start webpage,

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://www.example.com/`;

so this page is a double loading...

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 3):

1. It looks like you have a typo in your module definition. You have `module.export = {...}`, but correct usage is `module.exports = {...}`.
2. It is possible to not specify the page for the test. In this case, test starts from the 'blank' page and then you will be redirected to the `Role/login` page.